# admingenerator symfony2 CSS not found

Tags: css, symfony, admin-generator

I am trying to get started with admingenerator bundle for symfony2 on windows:

http://symfony2admingenerator.org/installation.html

I have followed the instruction for the out of the box, latest, nightly windows release.
When running the app-dev.php script the admin interface is shown but the css is broken.

I have good working knowledge with codeigniter but i am just starting with sympfony, would appreciate a hint on this.
As it is an unaltered distribution I hope there is an obvious solution. Thanks!

I have found a post experiencing this issue and the proposed solution was to use "Assetic Less". Attempts to configure accordingly to the scarce docu have been in vain. 
(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony2admingenerator/-d5eyFJ3NjU/44XmT3p2LvUJ)

The description:

The following css can't be resolved: cfc4cff__base.css_1.css instead the following error message stack is returned

> /* [exception] 500 | Internal Server Error |
>   Assetic\Exception\FilterException [message] An error occurred while
>   running: cmd /V:ON /E:ON /C
>   ""/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.7/bin/compass"
>   "compile" "C:\Users\bion\AppData\Local\Temp"
>   "--boring" "--images-dir"
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\nightly\app/../web/bundles/admingeneratoractiveadmintheme/images"
>   "--config"
>   "C:\Users\bion\AppData\Local\Temp\ass1F4.tmp"
>   "--sass-dir" "" "--css-dir" ""
>   "C:\Users\bion\AppData\Local\Temp\ass1F5.tmp.scss""
>
> Error Output: The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> Input: /* Active Admin CSS */ @import
>   "mixins/_all.css.scss";
>
> // Reset Away! @include global-reset;
>
> // Partials @import "_typography.css.scss"; @import
>   "_header.css.scss"; @import "_forms.css.scss";
>   @import "components/_comments.css.scss"; @import
>   "components/_flash_messages.css.scss"; @import
>   "components/_date_picker.css.scss"; @import
>   "components/_tables.css.scss";

and

```
        at n/a
            in C:\xampp\htdocs\nightly\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\Assetic\Exception\FilterException.php line 40

        at Assetic\Exception\FilterException::fromProcess(object(Process))
            in C:\xampp\htdocs\nightly\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\Assetic\Filter\CompassFilter.php line 294

        at Assetic\Filter\CompassFilter-&gt;filterLoad(object(FileAsset))
            in C:\xampp\htdocs\nightly\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\Assetic\Filter\FilterCollection.php line 62

        at Assetic\Filter\FilterCollection-&gt;filterLoad(object(FileAsset))
            in C:\xampp\htdocs\nightly\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset.php line 83

        at Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset-&gt;doLoad(&#039;/* Active Admin CSS */
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a quick and dirty solution to just add all.css stylesheet in one the main twig index template.